# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 1 elements

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')


url = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=207437&startdate=Jan%201%2C%201971&enddate=Jul%201%2C%202017&start={0}&num=30"
how_many_pages=3
start=0

for i in range(how_many_pages):
    new_url = url.format(start)
    page = requests.get(new_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='gf-table historical_price')[0]

    columns_header = [th.getText() for th in table.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')]
    data_rows=table.findAll('tr')[1:]
    data=[[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['td'])] for i in range(len(data_rows))]

    if start == 0:
        final_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns_header)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns_header)
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df],axis=0)
    start += 30
    final_df.to_csv('nse_data.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')


final_df.columns = ['Date']
final_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', utc=True)


df.plot(x='Date', y='Close')


plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

The data downloaded is in the following format

```
    "Date
"   "Open
"   "High
"   "Low
"   "Close
"   "Volume
"
0   "Jun 30, 2017
"   "9,478.50
"   "9,535.80
"   "9,448.75
"   "9,520.90
"   "-
"
1   "Jun 29, 2017
"   "9,522.95
"   "9,575.80
"   "9,493.80
"   "9,504.10
"   "-
```

For the time being I only want to plot `Date` (on X-axis) against `Close`  (on Y-axis)

However I am getting the error

`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 1 elements`

Answer (score 2):

- Your headers and data contain newline characters. `print(final_df.columns)` returns:

  ```
  Index(['Date\n', 'Open\n', 'High\n', 'Low\n', 'Close\n', 'Volume\n'], dtype='object')
  ```

  Use `rstrip` to get rid of them:

  ```
  columns_header = [th.getText().rstrip() for th in table.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')]
  ```

  and

  ```
  data = [[td.getText().rstrip() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['td'])] for i in range(len(data_rows))]
  ```
- `final_df.columns = ['Date']` produces your error. A dataframe requires as many headers as its number of columns. Therefore, in your case a list of 6 elements is expected. I'm not sure what you want to do here, I think you can simply remove this line.
- The format you specify for date parsing does not match your data `['Apr 4, 2017', 'Apr 5, 2017', 'Apr 6, 2017',...]`. Documentation on [format codes here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Use instead:

  ```
  final_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %d, %Y')
  ```
- Convert your data to numeric values so you can plot them:

  ```
  final_df['Close'] = [float(val.replace(',', '')) for val in final_df['Close']]
  ```
- Finally you can call:

  ```
  final_df.plot(x='Date', y='Close')
  ```