# Concatenating header list to Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am having trouble to concatenate 2 simple `DataFrames`. I upload first one `.txt` file containing the data set, and then another one containing the `header` of the previous dataset.

First I upload the 2 DataFrames:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_dir + file_name, sep = ',', header = None, encoding = 'latin-1', low_memory = False)
df_column_names = pd.read_csv(file_dir + file_name_cols, sep = ',', header = None, encoding = 'latin-1', low_memory = False)
```

Afterwards, I create a `list` of the header's `DataFrame` by first transposing the table, and the converting it into a `list`:

```
list_names = df_column_names.T.values.tolist()
```

Then, I finally create the desired `DataFrame`:

```
df.columns = list_names
```

But I receive the following error message:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 26 elements, new values
>   have 1 elements

The dimensions of my objects are:
`df` of size (204,26) and type `DataFrame`, `df_column_names` is size (1,26) and type `DataFrame`, `list_names` is size 26 and type `list`.

After reading other threads, the most similars were [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876939/valueerror-length-mismatch-expected-axis-has-6-elements-new-values-have-1-ele), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608203/length-mismatch-error-when-assigning-new-column-labels-in-pandas-dataframe). Nevertheless, after checking the indexes of my two DataFrames, both seem OK:

```
In [4]: print(df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=205, step=1)

In [5]: print(df_column_names.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)

In [6]: len(list_names)
Out[6]: 26
```

The look of `list_names` is the following:

```
In [7]: list_names
Out[7]: 
[['symboling'],
 ['normalized-losses'],
 ['make'],
 ['fuel-type'],
 ['aspiration'],
 ['num-of-doors'],
 ['body-style'],
 ['drive-wheels'],
 ['engine-location'],
 ['wheel-base'],
 ['length'],
 ['width'],
 ['height'],
 ['curb-weight'],
 ['engine-type'],
 ['num-of-cylinders'],
 ['engine-size'],
 ['fuel-system'],
 ['bore'],
 ['stroke'],
 ['compression-ratio'],
 ['horsepower'],
 ['peak-rpm'],
 ['city-mpg'],
 ['highway-mpg'],
 ['price']]
```

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list_names` is a *list of lists*. The requirement is to have a flat list.

You need to amend this line:

```
list_names = df_column_names.T.values.tolist()
```

To this:

```
df_column_names = df_column_names.transpose() # transpose dataframe if necessary
list_names = df_column_names[0].tolist()
```

You need to transpose your dataframe, as above, if your column names are in the first row rather than first column.

Comment: Hi @jpp thanks a lot for your answer. Your answer has made me see where my mistake was: in my ´df_column_names´ DataFrame, the column names weren't in the first column as 26 rows, but in the first row as 26 columns. I had to first transpose the DataFrame as this: df_column_names = df_column_names.transpose() , and the applying your response line: list_names = df_column_names[0].tolist(). Thanks a lot! Will mark as correct answer.

Comment: @NuValue, Excellent - glad this helped.